# Laravel echo send data when joining channel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-echo, broadcasting, pusher-js

How do I receive data when the client initially joins a channel?

Something like this:

```
Echo.channel('channel-name')
    .onjoin(function (data) {
        console.log(data) // Data received from server
    })
```

As soon when the client joins, the server should respond with data, preferably with PHP.

Comment: What information are you looking to receive from the server? Presence channels return information about the users in the channel at the time the client subscribes. If you require other data from your server then you could send a post request to your server to get the information. You could invoke this in a  `pusher:subscription_succeeded` binding so it occurs when the subscription is etablished

Comment: Don't know why I look for a complicated way, when it also works like that, thanks! But my application requires other data as soon as the subscription is succeeded. I may get data from the broadcasting server, before I acquire the other data.

Comment: @doydoy Guess it works for me, could you post this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presence channels return information about the users in the channel at the time the client subscribes.
If you require other data from your server then you could send a post request to your server to get the information. You could invoke this in a `pusher:subscription_succeeded` binding so it occurs as soon as the subscription is established.

Answer (score 0):

### **Edit:**

.here will display the data per user connected, which is not what I want.

---

I thought presence channel was what I was looking for. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#presence-channels

```
// Define channel
Broadcast::channel('channel-name', function () {
    if (/* Condition if user is allowed to join channel */) {
        return ['data' => 'your Data'];
    }
});


// Join channel
Echo.join('channel-name')
    .here(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
    })


// Event
class Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```